# x and y coordinates of a view changes when phone size changes and thus a view is placed at different position

Tags: android

I get coordinates of a view by converting them to dp and then store them . When a view is placed at same coordinates in another density phone, it appears on different position.
here is the code to take x and y position of a textview.

```
int e1x = getdps((int)view.getX());
int e1y = getdps((int)view.getY());

int getdps(int dp) {
    float metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (metrics * dp+0.5f);
}
```

I'm stuck here. I want the view to appear at same position on all Android phones.

Comment: could you give me more details about the required result?like an image of what you want to design

Comment: im placing a textview on image .store coordinates of x and y .when i see the same image on another high density phone /differernt dimension phone ,position of textview is different.

Comment: actually i can give you another solution instead of x and y but i need an image of final design to give you accurate solution

Comment: if you want to solve it by x and y you have to calculate x and y with ratio comparing to getIntrinsicHeight blah blah
it's a complex solution

Comment: why a image ?user places the textview at its desired position ,i store x and y coordinates .this is how it goes

Comment: okay ,give me a solution then easy.im not stick to x and y .i was using it just because i thought that could be the only way to do .its good to know that you have a better solution

Comment: ratio of x = (real width/scaled width)

Comment: ratioX * x = real x on the image

Comment: read width of the drawable is getIntrinsicWidth()

Comment: can you be more clear? may be a example will help me .

Comment: how to get scaled width ?

Comment: i added an answer

Answer (score 0):

X on screen is `imageView.getX()`.

real x of image is getting by:

`ratioOfWidth=imageView.getWidth()/imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()`

`real x = image x * ratioOfWidth;`

Same work for `real y`.

Check with `Paint app` if it's same as x of the code
in Paint app you can see bottom status the x and y when you move the mouse.

Second Solution:

calculate your design ratios by paint

for example my width is 100px and view start from 50px

so view is in .5 of width

then use LinearLayout or PercentRelativeLayout or better ConstraintLayout

in Constraint Layout i will put horizontal bias .5

Comment: i tried it.i need coordinates of textview so textview doesnt have getDrawable feature.

Comment: @AASH check my second solution else i don't know

Comment: sorry if i can't help you @AASH